# How to Refresh adf table after insert a new row

Tags: jpa, oracle10g, ejb, oracle-adf, weblogic12c

Hello I have two pages: the first is "creer dossier.jsf" where I can add a new row and the seconde page is "listdossier.jsf" inside it i have a read only table that contains the records of the first page.
when I create a record in the first page it persist in the database but can't appears in the table only when i redploy the application .
I want to get the newest records without redeploying the application..can someone help me please??
to create the table i just drag it from the data control.
I am using EclipseLink JPA as ORM and web logic 
I tried to delete the cache using from the persistanc.xml and em.refresh() and always the same problem
here's my table:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.collectionModel}"
var="row" rows="#{bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.rangeSize}"
emptyText="#{bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"rowBandingInterval="0"
fetchSize="#{bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.rangeSize}" id="t2"
partialTriggers="l1" width="796px"
immediate="false" binding="#{backingBeanScope.BeanDatabase.t2}">
<af:column headerText="ID_Dossier" id="c5" width="150"
inlineStyle="background-color:#b5ffde">
<af:link actionListener="#{bindings.setCurrentRowWithKeyValue.execute}"
 text="#{row.idDossier}"
 disabled="#{!bindings.setCurrentRowWithKeyValue.enabled}" id="l1"action="GoEditDossierBTEDEP1" inlineStyle="background-color:#b5ffde"/>
</af:column>
<af:column headerText="Client" id="c6" width="150"
inlineStyle="background-color:#b5ffde">
<af:outputText value="#{row.client}"
shortDesc="#{bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.hints.client.tooltip}"
id="ot6"/>
</af:column>
<af:column headerText="Ingénieur" id="c7" width="150"
inlineStyle="background-color:#b5ffde" headerClass="skin1.css">
<af:outputText value="#{row.ingAff}"shortDesc="#{bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.hints.ingAff.tooltip}"id="ot7"/>
</af:column>
<af:column headerText="Probléme" id="c8" width="300" inlineStyle="background-color:#b5ffde">
<af:outputText value="#{row.descriProb}"
 shortDesc={bindings.dossierFindAllParDepartementDBTE.hints.descriProb.tooltip}"
    id="ot8"/>
</af:column>
</af:table>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you cache the data for your read-only table in some session-scoped bean?

Answer (score 0):

In the task flow that navigates between the two pages, stick a method activity that does a call to the query and re-execute it before you go back to the first page.

Comment: thank you for help!!! but each page in a different task flow,cause i'm using them as menus!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in 2 ways:

1. Refresh the Page or the Particular component of second page on Submit of the first page.
2. Refresh the Iterator and VO after submitting the values in the first page